# Do I have to be REALLY LOUD to get a full mixed/belted voice?

Tags: voice

I'm trying to teach myself how to sing for 2 months now or something. I've looked on the internet to gather as much information as I could to make my journey as safe as possible but nobody mentions this in a at least "descriptive" way.

I can go as low as a C2 ... but that's a useless note, not strong enough and as high as E4/F4. I think F4 is my where my break is. Anyway, I know how to do the transition smoothly from chest to head without hearing the break but my problem is that when I sing rock/metal where I have to put more pressure I am VERY loud. I think I do have somewhat proper chord closure and what I'm really asking here is... Do I have to be THAT loud? Is that the right way?

I mean someone walked in the room last time I tried doing what I describe above and he glares at me...  I'm like "I know" and he said "No.... you really Don't! Last time you try to sing that song."

I bet I'm labeled as the crazy person in my neighborhood by now. So what gives? Any input would be welcomed.

Comment: In my experience, singing as quietly as possible helps my voice sound as good as possible and last as long as possible. You should find a teacher, even if for only a couple lessons. I'm pretty sure that singing really loud is not good for your voice.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need are vocal exercises to train that bridge between your head voice and your chest voice. No worries, all singers are stuck with this problem - even experienced ones! Try the exercises in this video, they should help!

and also more on singing right here: http://superiorsingingsuccess.weebly.com/home/how-to-sing-better-for-guys

hope this helps man!

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer.
I have to say that since I'm self taught I'm abusing vids like the above. I've watched them "all." 

I managed to fix my problem. The issue was a lowered soft palate. I thought I was rising it up enough but it could and did go MUCH further in which like a switch made me a better singer. It's weird how these things work. In just a moment of trying things out. The way I sing changed completely. It's not just the noise that it almost disappeared... I also can sing much more relaxed now, the tension goes to keeping the palate up and at The vocal chords.